# SSL certificate with imageView on Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to show picture that obtain from URLlink but I stuck in problem that's not trust in this URLlink. Then, it don't show anythings on screen. So, this is my Oncreate's code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        Bitmap bmp = null;

        ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String imageUrl = "10.34.250.12/api/config/v1/maps/imagesource/domain_0_1500368087062.jpg";
imgView.setImageBitmap(GetBitmapfromUrl("https://httpbin.org/image/png"));

        imgView.setTag("10.34.250.12/api/config/v1/maps/imagesource/domain_0_1500368087062.jpg");
        new DownloadImagesTask().execute(imgView);
}
```

and this is DownloadImageTask's code.

```
class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews){
        this.imageView = imageViews[0];
        return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    private Bitmap download_Image(String url){
        Bitmap bmp = null;

        try{
            URL urln = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)urln.openConnection();
            String UserCredentials = "dev : dev12345";
            String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString(UserCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
//            String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes);
            con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
//            con.setUseCaches(false);
//            con.setDoInput(true);
//            con.setDoOutput(true);
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            return bmp;
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

thanks for every helps .

Comment: Please add the SSL certificate error you faced with.

Comment: it's not error but it's doesn't show anything in screen. but when i access this url from googlechrome i must self-signed before i can access in.

Answer (score 0):

For https your may cast the result of openConnection to HttpsURLConnection

If you using untrust ssls you may create a X509Certificate with your keystore to use in the application, or create a X509 that ignores all certificates

Comment: in DownloadImageTask class ??

Comment: Yes, for more help you need to post your error stacktrace

Comment: it's not error but it don't show anythings on screen. but when i used postman to request httpRequest. it's works. So, i think that problem are on untrust ssl certificate. because when i access this urllink on googlechrome i must self-sign before access in link.

Comment: If you using untrust ssls you may create a X509Certificate with your keystore to use in the application, or create a X509 that ignores all certificates